# Proper login through social network in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, social-networking

In Java EE the common way of user authentication is to set up a realm in web.xml and do login in the following fashion:

```
 HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

 request.login(accountId, passwordHash);
```

Things become more interesting when a user access a web site through social network account. In this case we know his/her email (account name) but the user does not have a password.

I only came to the idea to generate a password for a user that logged in through social network and either pass it or it's salted hash to request.login().

Is there a common solution for this problem?

Are there any frameworks that already solve this problem?

Update. Maybe the whole approach combining Java EE realms with social networks login is wrong? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you save your user info(that is email and password) in any database?

Comment: Have you looked at Spring Social?

Comment: @Jhanvi Since a user can authenticate both through login/password and social networks, I save email and salted hash of his/her password in a database.

Comment: @chrylis We are using Java EE in our project. How good will it be to use both Java EE and Spring in a single application?

Comment: "Java EE" isn't a full stack per se; it's a collection of a bunch of different technologies, many of which Spring either uses directly (e.g., JSP and Bean Validation) or cooperates with nicely (JPA, JAAS). You'd need to see whether the integration overhead would be worth what you'd get from the existing code.

Comment: When the user logs in from a network, at that time you can save timestamp with the network id, and pass it as parameter in your request.login method.

Comment: @chrylis Maybe it is a good idea after all. Could you please share an example or more detailed explanation of how to combine authentication realm with Spring Social?

Comment: @Jhanvi Do you mean something like: request.login(userEmail, "facebook|" + timestamp); ? Why is it better than storing generated password's hash and passing it to request.login ?

Comment: @Proger its not better, just for the first time you can create it this way, and give option to the user to update his/her password, even if the user doesnt update it, you have the password itself in the format which can tell from which network the user loggedin and at what time., but that is if you are not storing the login time and info of user elsewhere , otherwise auto generated passwords are also fine, its just an alternative.